# Is it possible to configure a variation to only change the components 3D model?

Tags: altium

The PCB I am making has two variations, one of the differences is that the connectors have two different heights and need different 3D-models. It seems to be the case, that when a component variation uses a different footprint, Altium makes you place a whole new footprint in addition to the original variant.

One solution is to place the two footprints atop each other, but is there a way to simply change the 3D-model leaving everything else the same?